# looping through parameters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, parameters

I am writing a script that accepts some number of files as arguments and for each file, outputs a message:

**The size of FILENAME is SIZE kilobytes**

I am struggling on how to reference the parameters inside the while loop

this is my code

```
i=1
while [ $i -le $# ]
do
echo "The size of $(du -s $1 | cut -f2) is $(du -s $1 | cut -f1) kilobytes"
i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the values, not the index. Note this is all POSIX-standard shell.

```
for i in "$@"; do
    # Run du once, no need for cut
    read -r size dir <<EOF
$(du -s "$i")
EOF
    echo "The size of $dir is $size kilobytes"
done
```

You can replace the here document with a here string in `bash`:

```
read -r size dir <<< "$(du -s "$i")"
```

Comment: The canonical way to iterate over all arguments is `for i do` (`for i; do` is also accepted by all shells I know of.)

Comment: No, that's a short cut for if you omit the explicit sequence to iterate over.

Comment: It works perfectly, but I could not understand what EOF do

Comment: It's an arbitrary string, used to mark the end of the here document. Each of the following lines is used as standard input for the `read` command, until a line with *just* the `EOF` is found. You can use virtually any string you want in place of `EOF`, as long as you use a matching pair.